# Finding CDF/PDF of a function of a continuous random variable

Tags: probability

this is from a practice exam for a final, and I wasn't sure if my answer was correct, so I was looking for some guidance

Here is the question:
$\text{Let X be a continuous random variable with the probability distribution function }f(x) = ax^2 \text{ for }x \in (0,1)\text{ and }f(x) = 0\text{ for }x \notin (0,1).$

$1.\text{ What is }a \text{ ?}$

This part is pretty straight forward where $$\int_{0}^{1} ax^2 = \frac{ax^3}{3} = \frac{a}3 \Rightarrow a=3.  $$

$2. \text{Find the CDF of } X^2$
$$Y=X^2, F(Y) = P(Y < y) = P(X^2<y) = P(-\sqrt{y} \leq X \leq \sqrt{y} )$$
$$ =\int_{-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} 3x^2 = 2y^{3/2}$$
$$F_Y(y) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & y< 0 \\
      2y^{3/2} & 0\leq y\leq 1 \\
      1 & y > 1
   \end{cases}
$$

After this point is where I start to get iffy

$3.\text{ What is } P(X > X^2)\text{?}$
$$P(X>Y) = P(Y < X) = P(Y < x) = F(x) = 2x^{3/2}$$

4. Let $Y$ be another random variable which is independent of $X$. Suppose that it has the same probability distribution as  $X^2$. What is $P(X > Y)$?

Am I right to assume that it's the same as #3?

$5. \text{What is } P(X=Y)\text{?}$
$$f(y) = \int F(y) = \int 2y^{3/2} = 3\sqrt{y}$$
$$P(X = Y) = 3\sqrt{x}$$

Comment: 2 is incorrect. 3) X has value in $(0,1)$, therefore $X>X^2$ a.s 4) you know the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ as X and Y are independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a=3$ is correct.  Your answer for (2) is obviously wrong, because $2 y^{3/2}$ will be greater than $1$ for $y$ close to $1$.

You should get the CDF of $X$, from integrating $f(x)$, to be

$$ F_X(x) = \cases{0 & for $x < 0$\cr
                   x^3 & for $0 \le x \le 1$\cr
                   1 & for $x > 1$\cr} $$
Then $F_Y(y) = \mathbb P(X^2 \le y) = F_X(\sqrt{y})$ for $y \ge 0$ (and of course $0$ for $y < 0$.  Thus
$$ F_Y(y) = \cases{0 & for $y < 0$\cr
                   y^{3/2} & for $0 \le y \le 1$\cr
                   1 & for $y > 1$\cr}$$

For (3), note that $x > x^2$ means $x(1-x) > 0$, and this is true if and only if $0 < x < 1$.  So $\mathbb P(X > X^2) = \mathbb P(0 < X < 1) = \lim_{x \to 1-} F(x) - F(0) = 1$.

For (4),

$$ \mathbb P(X < Y) = \int_0^1 \int_x^1 f_X(x) f_Y(x) \; dy \; dx = \int_0^1 f_X(x) \mathbb P(x < Y)\; dx = 
      \int_0^1 3 x^2 (1-x^{3/2})\; dx = \frac{1}{3}$$

For (5), the answer should be $0$, because the line $x=y$ has area $0$.

Comment: The thing I'm confused about is why we ignore the $-\sqrt{y}$ component. Is it because X can't be negative?

Comment: Also I mistyped #4, and put the wrong inequality sign there

Comment: For #4, I got $$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x} f(x)f(y) dxdy = \int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{9}{4}x^2y^{1/2} dxdy = 1/3$$ which does not seem to agree with your answer, so I'm confused

Comment: @DavidKang
you got it right: $-\sqrt{y}$ is ignored because we know that $X$ only takes values in $(0,1)$. Or put differently, we know $f(x)=0$ for $x \notin (0,1)$, so the integral from $-\sqrt{y}$ to 0 would be zero as well.

Comment: @DavidKang To put it another way, yes, you *can* write $$F_Y(y) = \Pr[-\sqrt{y} \le X \le \sqrt{y}] = \int_{x=-\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt{y}} f_X(x) \, dx,$$ but from that point forward, you must write $$\int_{x=-\sqrt{y}}^{0} 0 \, dx + \int_{x=0}^{\sqrt{y}} 3x^2 \, dx,$$ because $$f_X(x) = \begin{cases} 3x^2, & 0 \le x \le 1 \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}. \end{cases}$$  It is not true that $f_X(x) = 3x^2$ everywhere.